# How to define AVRO route in Camel with protocol declaration?

Tags: apache-camel, avro

I have AVRO protocol like this:

```
{
  "namespace": "org.apache.camel.avro.generated",
  "protocol": "KeyValueProtocol",
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "Key", "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        { "name": "key", "type": "string"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Value", "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        { "name": "value", "type": "string"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "messages": {
    "put": {
      "request": [{"name": "key", "type": "Key"}, {"name": "value", "type": "Value"} ],
      "response": "null"
    },
    "get": {
      "request": [{"name": "key", "type": "Key"}],
      "response": "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

Camel route:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component public class Computations extends RouteBuilder {


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("avro:http:localhost:12345?protocol=KeyValueProtocol")
                .process(exchange->{
                    System.out.println(exchange);
                })
                .to("log:foo")
                .end();
    } }
```

and during compilation I got error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:schema (default) on project
>   tradersbook-mt-common-computations: Execution default of goal
>   org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:schema failed: No type:
>   {"namespace":"org.apache.camel.avro.generated","protocol":"KeyValueProtocol","types":[{"name":"Key","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"key","type":"string"}]},{"name":"Value","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"value","type":"string"}]}],"messages":{"put":{"request":[{"name":"key","type":"Key"},{"name":"value","type":"Value"}],"response":"null"},"get":{"request":[{"name":"key","type":"Key"}],"response":"Value"}}}
>   -> [Help 1]

dependencies:

[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.18.5:compile

[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile

any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case only issue was that my file had wrong extension.
Protocol cannot be in file with extension '.**avsc**'

'.**avpr**' and '.**avdl**' are working fine with maven plugin (fine == 'no errors during compilation')

Looks like change of this extension provide to ignore this data by plugin.